# how to make Spark jdbc connection to Sqlserver using keytab in cluster mode

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, kerberos

All,

per enterprise policy, we need to use the Windows Authentication for connecting to Sql-server from spark.
Current solution works only in --master = local and not in the yarn mode. Can you please help if anyone have a solution which can be used ;

Below code works in "local" mode and not in clustered mode;

```
val sqlDriverName = "com.ms.sqlServer.jdbc.SqlserverDriver"
val principal = "user@Domain"

val keytab = "path to keytab"

val connectStr = "jdbc:sqlserver"//<host>;database=db;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos"
val DF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("url",connectStr )
            .option("dbTable","tablename")
            .option("driver",sqlDriverName )
            .option("principal",principal )
           .option("keytab",keytab )
           .load()
```

Thanks
ssi

Comment: Can you check out this : https://datamountaineer.com/2016/01/15/spark-jdbc-sql-server-kerberos/

Comment: I tried to use - but does not seems to be working .. have you used that ?